# Laravel routes are returning "404 Not Found" error after moving to production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, apache2.4

I wrote an application using Laravel 5.2. It developed the application using XAMP server on my local machine and everything is good and tested.

Now, I am ready to move the application to a production environment. On a new server running on Windows Server 2008 R2, I installed Apache 2.4.18 and and PHP 5.6.18. I enabled the following php extensions

1. OpenSSL PHP Extension
2. PDO PHP Extension
3. Mbstring PHP Extension
4. Tokenizer PHP Extension

I was able to use `php artisan migrate` command to create my databases. But, non of my routes are accessible. When I go to https://sub.example.com it displays "Laravel 5" which tells me that Laravel is setup.

Why non of my routes are working?
Every route I go it I get a 404 Not Found error.

What else I need to do in order for the routes to work?

Comment: Did you upload all files to the server after laravel install?

Comment: is it the laravel's 404? or apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the following steps

```
Open apache httpd.conf and find this line :

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

1. Uncomment this line (remove the #)
2. Save httpd.conf
3. Restart Apache